# How can a webcam be accessed using opencv with python?

Tags: python, opencv

This is the code that I currently have:

```py
import cv2, time

video=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
check, frame=video.read()

print(check)
print(frame)

cv2.imshow("Capturing", frame)
cv2.waitkey(0)
video.release()
```

The code is showing a syntax error.

The error:

```py
False
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Stagiair/Desktop/aaa.py", line 9, in <module>
    cv2.imshow("Capturing", frame)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-95hbg2jt\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:376: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'
```

Comment: *The code is showing a syntax error.* - then it would make a lot of sense to tell us what error you got, right?!

Comment: I've edited but couldn't guess what his error was. I'll run the code myself and then update it.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Check if the webcam is opened correctly
if not cap.isOpened():
    raise IOError("Cannot open webcam")

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, None, fx=0.5, fy=0.5, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    cv2.imshow('Input', frame)

    c = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if c == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This should work.

If you have problem installing **CV2** you can try the following steps:

1. Open command prompt. (Search CMD in windows search bar.)
2. Run following command:

```
python -m pip install –upgrade pip
```

3. Install opencv using following command:

```
pip install opencv-python.
```

In case you are using Anaconda, then follow the steps down below.

4. Open command prompt.
5. Update conda navigator with following command:

```
conda update anaconda-navigator
conda update navigator-updater
```

6. Install opencv using following command:

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```

or

```
conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/menpo opencv
```

Comment: No the code you have given is not working. It's still showing some kind of error, the error is given below

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Shovik/Desktop/webcam.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'


How to solve the problem?

Comment: @ShovikChoudhary Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27723986) your question to show the actual error you are getting. All of the information should be on the question. And, a "ModuleNotFoundError" is not a syntax error.

Comment: @ShovikChoudhary This means you have not installed CV2. To install open CMD and type `pip install opencv-python`. Next time inspect what error you are getting and analize it before you ask ;)

Comment: @MarkdG I have tried it before but I still found a syntax error
Its flashing red in the "install" command of "pip install opencv-python" and showing syntax error

Comment: Is it showing the same syntax error as before or did it change?

Comment: No, it does not change. its showing the same syntax error

Comment: The error is literally showing that the module is not installed and you have tried installing it? I can't help you with this problem since I do not know what exactly is going wrong. I recommend searching on google why you get this error and if you still can't figure out what's going wrong then create a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Comment: @MarkdG Please tell me how to install open cv in python

If possible then answer the question using images

Comment: I will edit my old answer and put the answer on your current question on the bottom.

Comment: @MarkdG Thank you for your kind attention to my problem. Now I can access the webcam through python

Comment: If you could close the question than that would be appreciated. This way the community bot won't push this question around as unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is showing that `video.read()` is returning `(False, None)`. This is telling you that the read failed. The failure you're seeing is the result of passing `None` to `cv2.imshow()`.

On one of my laptops, it take a few attempts for the video to 'warm up' and start returning images. Arranging to ignore some number of `(False, None)` returns is usually sufficient.